# WCF JSON serialization is inconsistent so how can it be deserialized correctly?

Tags: c#, json, wcf, serialization

I have a serializable polymorphic type, and a service contract.

```cs
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(SomethingA))]
[KnownType(typeof(SomethingB))]
public class Something
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Item1 { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Item2 { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class SomethingA : Something
{ }

[DataContract]
public class SomethingB : Something
{ }

[ServiceContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(SomethingA))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(SomethingB))]
public interface ITesting
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        UriTemplate = "use-something",
        Method = "POST")]
    Something UseSomething();

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        UriTemplate = "use-polymorphic-somethings",
        Method = "POST")]
    List<Something> UsePolymorphicSomethings();

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        UriTemplate = "throw-web-exception",
        Method = "POST")]
    void ThrowServerException();
}
```

...and an implementation of that contract.

```cs
using System.Net;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;

public class Testing : ITesting
{
    public Something UseSomething()
    {
        SomethingA a = new SomethingA();
        a.Item1 = 2;
        a.Item2 = "b";
        return a;
    }

    public List<Something> UsePolymorphicSomethings()
    {
        List<Something> retVal = new List<Something>();
        retVal.Add(new SomethingA { Item1 = 1, Item2 = "1" });
        retVal.Add(new SomethingB { Item1 = 1, Item2 = "1" });

        return retVal;
    }

    public void ThrowServerException()
    {
        try
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Bad news.");
        }
        catch (ApplicationException e)
        {
            throw new WebFaultException<ApplicationException>(e, HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
        }
    }
}
```

I have some functional tests in another assembly.

```cs
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;

[TestMethod]
public void UseSomething_WebTest()
{
    using (HttpClient http = new HttpClient())
    {
        http.BaseAddress = TestUtil.TestsBaseAddress;

        HttpResponseMessage response = http.PostAsJsonAsync("use-something",
            new StringContent(string.Empty)).Result;

        string ret1 = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        // Deserializes SomethingA as Something.
        Stream stream = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Something));
        Something ret = (Something)serializer.ReadObject(stream);

        // FAILS.
        Assert.AreEqual(typeof(SomethingA), ret.GetType());
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void UsePolymorphicSomethings_WebTest()
{
    using (HttpClient http = new HttpClient())
    {
        http.BaseAddress = TestUtil.TestsBaseAddress;

        HttpResponseMessage response = http.PostAsJsonAsync("use-polymorphic-somethings",
            new StringContent(string.Empty)).Result;

        string ret2 = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        // Deserializes SomethingA and SomethingB correctly.
        Stream stream = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<Something>));
        List<Something> somethings = (List<Something>)serializer.ReadObject(stream);

        // SUCCEEDS.
        Assert.AreEqual(typeof(SomethingA), somethings[0].GetType());
        Assert.AreEqual(typeof(SomethingB), somethings[1].GetType());
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void ThrowServerException1_WebTest()
{
    using (HttpClient http = new HttpClient())
    {
        http.BaseAddress = TestUtil.TestsBaseAddress;

        HttpResponseMessage response = http.PostAsync("throw-web-exception",
           new StringContent(string.Empty)).Result;

        Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, response.StatusCode);

        string ret3 = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        // Deserializes ApplicationException as Exception.
        Stream stream = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Exception));
        Exception e = (Exception)serializer.ReadObject(stream);

        // FAILS.
        Assert.AreEqual(typeof(ApplicationException), e.GetType());
    }
}
```

In UseSomething_WebTest ret1 is:

```
"{\"Item1\":2,\"Item2\":\"b\"}"
```

...with no type information embedded unsurprisingly the DataContractJsonSerializer fails to deserialize the correct type of the object that was returned.

In UsePolymorphicSomethings_WebTest ret2 is:

```
"[{\"__type\":\"SomethingA:#InSite8WebServiceLib\",\"Item1\":1,\"Item2\":\"1\"},{\"__type\":\"SomethingB:#InSite8WebServiceLib\",\"Item1\":1,\"Item2\":\"1\"}]"
```

...with type information embedded in the form of __type entries which the DataContractJsonSerializer correctly deserializes.

In ThrowServerException1_WebTest ret3 is:

```
"{\"ClassName\":\"System.ApplicationException\",\"Message\":\"Bad news.\",\"Data\":null,\"InnerException\":null,\"HelpURL\":null,\"StackTraceString\":\"   at InSite8WebServiceLib.Testing.ThrowServerException() in d:\\\\SvnSource\\\\Hammersmith\\\\trunk\\\\VisualStudioProjects\\\\InSite8WebService\\\\InSite8WebServiceLib\\\\Testing\\\\Testing.cs:line 74\",\"RemoteStackTraceString\":null,\"RemoteStackIndex\":0,\"ExceptionMethod\":\"8\\u000aThrowServerException\\u000aInSite8WebServiceLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null\\u000aInSite8WebServiceLib.Testing\\u000aVoid ThrowServerException()\",\"HResult\":-2146232832,\"Source\":\"InSite8WebServiceLib\",\"WatsonBuckets\":null}"
```

...with type information embedded in the form of a ClassName entry which the DataContractJsonSerializer fails to deserialize correctly.

So my question is this. Why for a single WCF WebHttp endpoint do several WebInvoke attributed methods return several different formats of JSON only one of which the DataContractJsonSerializer can actually deserialize, and how do I fix it so that it works properly?

Answer (score 0):

You can force the DataContractJsonSerializer to always emit type information by overloading the constructor. Then you set the **alwaysEmitTypeInformation** argument to True.

Some more information on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412170.aspx)

Comment: I've seen that page before I find it quite confused. In the context of a WCF service the service library itself has no idea of the data transmission format being used, that's determined by configuration and handled automatically by the WCF framework, that's the whole point of using WCF in the first place. Since the service library doesn't know whether the transmission format is JSON or XML how can the service library code manually perform the necessary serialization?

Comment: If a webservice method returns a CustomObject type how would an implementation of that method that manually generates a JSON string even compile since it wouldn't then have a CustomObject to return? It seems you'd have to override the configuration with a hard coded implementation, and remove all the static typing from the webservice implementation and define every method to return a raw HttpResponse or something.

Comment: Have you tried to use a different Json library? Newtonsoft Json.net?

Comment: For the deserialization, yes I have but I couldn't get it to work. What I really want to know though is why is a single WCF webservice emitting multiple incompatible forms of JSON in the first place.